# Javascript taking div data with JS

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```html
<div class="takeIDfromhere">400788381251</div>
```

JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    var ID = document.getElementsByClassName('.takeIDfromhere');
    for(var i=0; i < ID.length; i++) { 
        document.write('\<div class="testclass">'+ID[i]+'</div> \ ');
    }
</script>
```

My point is, JavaScript must run when document ready.
This did not work.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Put JS <script> tag at the end of body (before </body>).

Comment: javascript runs when ever put them, not after document loaded. you can run javascript after document loaded using jQuery: $(document).ready(function () { //Code })

Answer (score 2):

It's the stray period.

```
var ID= document.getElementsByClassName('takeIDfromhere')
```

This should work. But your `document.write` code might not do what you think it's doing. The `\` characters don't make sense to me, nor does the way you're using `ID[i]`. Try replacing it with `document.write("test")` or something and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the . (period) from your class selector and if you want to get the actual ID make sure you are grabbing the innerHTML.

```
var ID= document.getElementsByClassName('takeIDfromhere');
for(var i=0; i < ID.length; i++) { 
  console.log('\<div class="testclass">'+ID[i].innerHTML+'</div> \ ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put  tag at end of the body or handle on document ready event

```
 <script>
document.ready = function() {var ID= document.getElementsByClassName('.takeIDfromhere');
for(var i=0; i < ID.length; i++) { 
  document.write('\<div class="testclass">'+ID[i]+'</div> \ ');
}
     }
 </script>
```